# Does local non-static variable get same memory address each time function/method is called?

Tags: c++, variables, static

I have made a fun called show()
in it i have declared a static and a non -static variable ;
I am observing one thing that each time my non-static local variables are getting same memory address when i am calling it .

i just want to know that this happens always or it is just a coincident;

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
void show()
{
  static int x = 10;  
   int y = 20; 
 
  cout<<"Address of y = "<< &y<< endl; 
  cout<< "x = "<< x<< " , y = "<< y<< endl;

  x++;
  y++;
}

int main()
{
  show();

  int x = 10; 
  cout<< x<< endl; 
  cout<< "len = "<< strlen("Kumar")<< endl; 

   show();
  show();
  return 0;
}
```

```
Out put of the program 
Address of y = 0xd01f5ffc6c
x = 10 , y = 20
10
len = 5
Address of y = 0xd01f5ffc6c
x = 10 , y = 20
Address of y = 0xd01f5ffc6c
x = 10 , y = 20
```

Comment: Do you know how automatically-scoped objects work? How a stack works?

Comment: If that *were* the case, then how would a local, automatic variable be able to handle *recursive* function calls?

Comment: try  calling show from inside another function which is then called from main

Comment: Add this code: `void g() { show(); }` and add `g();` to `main`.

Comment: you can add `if (x % 2) show()` at the bottom of `show()` to see what Adrian refered to

Comment: (And when trying the suggestion of @PeteBecker, don't use compiler optimization flags.)

Comment: @peteBecker i tried your suggestion but still variable y is getting same memory location each time it is called . void g() { show(); } main() { g(); g(); g() return 0; }

Comment: @samVarshavchik i know that as of now  i  am in sem 1 in my graduation . could just explain me in brief how

Comment: @AdrianMole I agree with you but in this  case how it is happing . it means this is coincident ;  should i consider it so. but when i tried "peteBecker" suggetstion this time also it is geting same memory location .

Comment: @AdrianMole  IN recusive call  y is getting different memory location . i think that one is just a coincident . i just want your opinion in this in coincident think. Thanks for the help . jai Hind(from India)

Comment: @AdrianMole I have observed an Interesting thing. y gets different memory location in recursive call but on every fresh call  of  show() y gets the same memory location as it got in first call and in recursive of show() in second fresh call y got the exactly the same memory address as  y has got in recusive call of first call  : means                                                                            &y1 == &y2   and     &y1~ == &y2~                             where &yn --> Address of y in nth call &yn~ --->     address of y in recursive call of nth call.  i hope i make my self clear.

Comment: @PrashantKumarGupta — I said to **add** `g();` to `main`. Don’t remove the calls to `show();`. The calls to `show()` from `main` ought to show a different address from the calls in `g`.

Answer (score 0):

It's related entirely to your call stack.

I added this method to your code:

```
void foo() {
    cout << "\nCalled from Foo.\n";
    show();
}
```

I then called `foo()` from `main()`. My output:

```
-$ g++ Foo.cpp -o Foo && Foo
Address of y = 0x7ffc709566d4
x = 10 , y = 20
10
len = 5
Address of y = 0x7ffc709566d4
x = 11 , y = 20
Address of y = 0x7ffc709566d4
x = 12 , y = 20

Called from Foo.
Address of y = 0x7ffc709566c4
x = 13 , y = 20
```

As you can see, it moved.

You should take the time to learn about stacks and the stack pointer, and how C and C++ store local variables.

Comment: Thank you very much for your guidance I got the concept.